# IIS doesn't recognise PHP tags for 'simple' Laravel routes only

Tags: php, laravel, iis

There are plenty of similar questions out there, but none that I've found resolve my specific problem.  I'm quite sure it's a configuration in my local IIS server, but I haven't been able to work it out myself.  FYI, my local dev machine is Windows 11, and I'm running IIS 10.

I have the following simple code in my Laravel `routes/web.php` file:

```php
Route::get('/info', function() { return '<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html><head><title>Testing</title></head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello from simple route</p>
        <p><?php
            echo phpinfo();
        ?></p>
    </body></html>'; });
Route::get('/info2', function() { return view('info'); });
```

Then I have the `resources/views/info.blade.php` file that looks like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Info Test 2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello from Blade Template</p>
    <p><?php
        echo phpinfo();
    ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

When I access `http://myserver/info2` in the browser, I get a nicely formatted PHP-info page as one would expect.  This proves that PHP is running correctly on my IIS setup.

But when I access `http://myserver/info`, I only get text from paragraph 1 of the HTML document, saying "Hello from simple route".  PHP-info is not rendered, and looking at the dev-tools output we can see that the `<?php` tags are commented out:

[image]

I understand that this is because IIS isn't recognising that it it dealing with a `*.php` file, and therefore doesn't realise that it should pass the response through its PHP parser.  But what I don't understand is why it doesn't work only for "simple" Laravel routes compared with Blade templates.  (If I understood why, I'd probably be able to work out which IIS config to change to fix it).

Under the IIS server "Handler Mappings", I have the following setup:

[image]

I've tried setting up a `*.html` and a `*` path to the above config, so that it doesn't always look for a PHP file to call the FastCGI/PHP processor, but none of this has worked.  Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: This has nothing to do with IIS. Your route is returning a simple string with php code in it. This code will never be executed.

Comment: When you return in `'/info'` a string it will not be parsed as a file like `resources/views/info.blade.php`. It will be just returned as string. So `<?php ?>` will not be parsed by PHP.

Comment: @stefket Okay - so you're saying that it would work the same way under Apache of Nginx ?  PS: your comments sound more like answers than comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you return in **/info** a string, it will not be parsed as a file like **resources/views/info.blade.php**.
It will be just returned as string.
So `<?php ?>` will not be parsed by PHP.

This will work:

```
Route::get('/info', function() { 

ob_start();
phpinfo();
$phpinfo = ob_get_clean();

return '<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html><head><title>Testing</title></head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello from simple route</p>
        <p>'.$phpinfo.'</p>
    </body></html>'; 
});

Route::get('/info2', function() { return view('info'); });
```

Why i am using `ob_start()/ob_get_clean()`?
Look here https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.phpinfo.php

`phpinfo()` returns a bool, not the content itself.
The content will be outputed directly. So if you want to catch it and write it into a variable you can use `ob_start()/ob_get_clean()` to do that.